# Changing Action On Forms

Tags: javascript

Trying to just put together some simple javascript to change the action location on a form, this is the code i'm using

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("wpcf7-form");
    x[0].action = "process/formdata.php";
</script>
```

However nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you submit the form? If no then of course nothing happens

Comment: Can you post your HTML? Maybe the class name is spelled wrong?

Comment: Class name is 100% accurate. Im checking the action via inspect element tool

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change form's action attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169844/change-forms-action-attribute)

Comment: Thank you Massimiliano Carosi, using documentready solved it